# Get option name attribute value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the name attribute value to an input(`#currency_sym`).

HTML:

```
<select id="cur_rate" onchange="changeFunc();">
     {{#each currencies}}
        <option name="{{this.symbol}}">{{this.currency}}</option>
     {{/each}}
</select>
<input type="text" id="currency_sym">
```

Javascript function:

```
function changeFunc() {
   $('#currency_sym').val($(".currateopt").attr("name"));
}
```

When I tried selecting various options values. But it always shows only one symbol. What is the problem there?

Comment: One problem: You cannot have an input field inside a select.

Comment: @Tokant Ut was my mistake. I corrected now on my question. In the real scenario, it is out of `select`

Comment: Another problem: Your onchange function selects the option with classname 'currateopt', but all of your options have this class, so it will show the attribute name of the last one.

Comment: Your `select` does not have a `name` attribute.

Comment: Another problem: Your id attribute for each option is missing ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of the selected option, change your function as follows:

```
function changeFunc() {
   $('#currency_sym').val($("#cur_rate").find("option:selected").attr("name"));
}
```

Comment: @user_v12 Glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `option:selected` to target the selected option from the passed element:

**Demo:**

```js
function changeFunc(el) {
   $('#currency_sym').val($(el).find('option:selected').attr("name"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="curratesec" id="cur_rate" onchange="changeFunc(this);">
     <option selected disabled>--Select Currency--</option>
     <option class="currateopt" id="id1" value="1" 
              name="symbol1">Dollar</option>
              <option class="currateopt" id="id2" value="2" 
              name="symbol2">Pound</option>
     <input type="text" id="currency_sym" name="currency_sym">
</select>
```

Comment: This also works well as I expected. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -3):

You can try

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="test" name="test" onclick="myFunction(this);">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
function myFunction(obj){
alert(obj.name)
}
```

OR

```
var obj = document.getElementById("test");
alert(obj.name);
```

Regards

Comment: please, test this
var obj = document.getElementById("test");
alert(obj.name);